# port number in URL

Tags: web-services, port, block

we currently have a web service hosted on our server and the link to the service is something like this: www.something.com:8041/MyService.asmx

our client cant open that link in their browser or connect to the service through the app. They found out that port 8041 is blocked.... this doesnt make sense to me, that port number is in the URL why would blocking ports have anything to do with that? its not looking the request is going out through port 8041?

We are going to unblock port 8041 at the client but that doesnt make sense, the port 8041 is for our servers benefit and has been unblocked...

Comment: because 8041 is not a standard port, and if 8041 gets opened up, what's to say that some OTHER system isn't using 8041 for a botnet C&C or whatever? just because YOU keep a car on your driveway doesn't mean someone else can't park a nuke trailer on theirs. "but they're both driveways!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, actually going to http://www.something.com:8041/MyService does in fact go through port 8041, and if you have a group of clients sitting behind one firewall (e.g. business 1) trying to access a server behind a second firewall (e.g. business 2), you need to make sure both firewalls are setup to allow this.

If you don't want to have to go around opening ports, a common solution is to configure a webserver (nginx, varnish, etc.) that is listening on port 80 (or 443) that reverse proxies to whatever service is listening on the non-standard port.

Comment: thought when i put a link in the browser, regardless if theresa port number in there,  the request will go through the default port number the web browser uses?